# Is $xx^T$ the Hessian of anything?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-optimization

Let $x$ be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Let $xx^T$ be the outer-product of this vector with itself.

Does there exist any function $f(x): \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $xx^\top$ is its Hessian?

Comment: Do you mean to say that the Hessian is constant? Or that it is symmetric and positive semidefinite at each point, but the $x$ is allowed to vary?

Comment: @Arthur $\nabla^2 f(x) = xx^\top$. That's all. $xx^\top $ is always symmetric and PSD regardless of what $x$ is.

Comment: I'm working on an answer right now by letting $f$ be an arbitrary homogeneous polynomial of degree $4$ and differentiating to find what the coefficients have to be. Almost done.

Comment: Oh, right. Same $x$ as input to $f$ as in the Hessian. I see. It's just that when you say "let $x$ be a vector in $\Bbb R^n$" it sounds like you're taking one particular vector and using only that one.

Comment: Disappointingly, according to my calculations, there is no homogeneous polynomial of degree $4$ which has the given Hessian.

Comment: Making the somewhat obvious guess $f(x) = \frac{1}{8} \sum_{i,j= 1}^n x_i^2 x_j^2$ gives you a Hessian with the correct off diagonal elements, but the diagonal elements end up being $x_i^2 + \frac{1}{2} \sum_j x_j^2$, which isn't what we want. In fact, it seems like there is no hope given the answers below. I must say, I find it surprising that this problem can't be solved. I'd wager this has some significant implications or can be seen as a consequence of some significant result.

Comment: @Charles See Ted Shifrin's answer for how it is a consequence of the symmetry of mixed partial derivatives, which is pretty significant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such function in general. Consider the 2D case. We have $H=\begin{bmatrix}x^2 &xy\\ xy &y^2\end{bmatrix}$, therefore $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}=xy$ and $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 x}=x^2,\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 y}=y^2$. We have

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 x}=x^2\Rightarrow f(x,y)=\frac{x^4}{12}+xg(y)+h(y)\Rightarrow \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 y}=xg''(y)+h''(y)=y^2\Rightarrow h(y)=\frac{y^4}{12}\\,g''(y)=0$$

Thus $f(x,y)=\frac{x^4}{12}+\frac{y^4}{12}+xg(y)$, now there is the finishing touch $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}=g'(y)=xy$ which is contradiction, because we are only expecting a funcyion of $y$ but we have $xy$. If you start integrating with respect to $y$ first, you arrive at $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}=l'(x)=xy$ for some function $l(x)$ (the problem is symmetric, order of integration is not important).

Comment: Note that a far easier argument is to use equality of mixed third-order partial derivatives. Compare $f_{xxy}$ and $f_{xyx}$.

Comment: Yup, you are right, that's a nice argument, I think you should add it as another answer.

Comment: There is a solution for $n=1$. Your argument applies to all bigger $n$.

Answer (score 6):

Note that if such an $f$ exists, it must be $C^3$, so mixed third-order partial derivatives must be equal. When $i\ne j$ we have
$$f_{iij} = 0 \quad\text{but}\quad f_{iji} = x_j.$$